# How do i compile a c program without all the bloat?

Tags: c, x86, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to learn x86. I thought this would be quite easy to start with - i'll just compile a very small program basically containing nothing and see what the compiler gives me. The problem is that it gives me a ton of bloat. (This program cannot be run in dos-mode and so on) 25KB file containing an empty main() calling one empty function.

How do I compile my code without all this bloat? (and why is it there in the first place?)

Comment: (this page might be amusing on this topic, although it's for Linux rather than Windows: http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)

Comment: And what flags are you using? Optimizations make a *huge* difference. Generally, C compiler output is not only terse and efficient, but so clever your eyes will pop out.

Comment: The bloat is there because operating systems and consequently the executables they can process are complex. You could try using Linux and compiling to the `a.out` format, that might be simpler than ELF or PE.

Comment: I'm currently running codeblocks, default, on windows 7. I'll give it a try in linux next week.

Comment: delnan: `a.out` is both the ancient file format and the default name a compiler gives to the compiled output on Unix. The file name no longer hints to the file format, though.

Comment: @Inerdia: Is anything still using that file format? Many C compilers from this century will still call the output file `a.out` by default, but AFAIK none of them still use that format (except perhaps on ancient platforms that use it, if they are supported at all). On Linux since kernel 1.2, ELF is used, I'd be surprised if non-ancient versions still have any support for the `a.out` format.

Comment: @Joey: Yes, I realized that after posting and replaced the original complaint with a different one ;)

Comment: @delnan I meant compiling to the format by poking around the GCC flags to see if there's one to force it.

Comment: I can't believe you didn't imagine it would be necessary to include details of what compiler you were using, and how you are linking your executable. Rather than ranting about bloat you ought to get the details right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executable formats contain a bit more than just the raw machine code for the CPU to execute. If you want that then the only option is (I think) a DOS .com file which essentially is just a bunch of code loaded into a page and then jumped into. Some software (e.g. Volkov commander) made clever use of that format to deliver quite much in very little executable code.

Anyway, the PE format which Windows uses contains a few things that are specially laid out:

- A DOS stub saying "This program cannot be run in DOS mode" which is what you stumbled over
- several sections containing things like program code, global variables, etc. that are each handled differently by the executable loader in the operating system
- some other things, like import tables

You may not need some of those, but a compiler usually doesn't know you're trying to create a tiny executable. Usually nowadays the overhead is negligible.

There is [an article out there](http://www.phreedom.org/solar/code/tinype/) that strives to create the tiniest possible PE file, though.

Answer (score 2):

You might get better result by digging up older compilers. If you want binaries that are very bare to the bone COM files are really that, so if you get hold of an old compiler that has support for generating COM binaries instead of EXE you should be set. There is a long list of free compilers at http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml, I assume that Borland's Turbo C would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The bloated module could be the loader (operating system required interface) attached by linker. Try adding a module with only something like:

`void foo(){}`

and see the disassembly (I assume that's the format the compiler 'gives you'). Of course the details vary much from operating systems and compilers. There are so many!